# Speeding Up Data Transfer Using Pyserial in Python

Tags: python, io, serial-port, pyserial

I have created a data transfer program using python and the pyserial module. I am currently using it to communicate text file over a radio device between a Raspberry Pi and my computer. The problem is, the file I am trying to send, which contains 5000 lines of text and is 93.0 Kb in size is taking quite a while to send. To be exact, it takes about a full minute. I need this to be done within seconds. Here is the following code, I am sure that there are many optimizations that can be made with file reading and such that would increase the data transfer speed. My radio device has a data speed of 250 kbps, which is obviously not being reached. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code to send(located on raspberry pi)

```
def s_file():

    print 'start'

    readline = lambda : iter(lambda:ser.read(1),"\n")
    name = "".join(readline())
    print name
    file_loc = directory_name + name

    sleep(1)

    print('Waiting for command from client to send file...')    

    while "".join(readline()) != "<<SENDFILE>>":                 
        pass

    with open(file_loc) as FileObj:
        for lines in FileObj:
            ser.write(lines)

    ser.write("\n<<EOF>>\n")

    print 'done'
```

Code to receive(on my laptop)

```
def r_f_bird(self): #send command to bird to start func,
    if ser_open == True:


        readline = lambda : iter(lambda:ser.read(1),"\n")

        NAME = self.tb2.get()

        ser.write('/' + NAME)

        print NAME
        sleep(0.5)
        ser.write('\n<<SENDFILE>>\n')

        start = clock()
        with open(str(NAME),"wb") as outfile:
            while True:
                line = "".join(readline())
                if line == "<<EOF>>":
                    break
                print >> outfile, line
        elapsed = clock() - start
        print elapsed


        ser.flush()

    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Are you setting the baud rate of the serial port? By default, I think pyserial sets it to 9600.

Comment: I have tried setting the baudrate to 230400 baud from 9600. I get no errors, but the time it takes to send the file is exactly the same. I have timed it. And what's weird is that the code outputs that the transfer only takes 2 seconds whereas my physical timer shows that the process takes nearly 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the overhead of `ser.read(1)` is slowing things down. It seems like you have a `\n` at the end of each line, so try using pySerial's `readline()` method rather than rolling your own. Changing `line = "".join(readline())` to `line = ser.readline()` ought to do it. You will also need to change your loop end condition to `== "<<EOF>>\n"`.

You may also need to add a `ser.flush()` on the writing side.